# How can show my series converges to zero

Tags: summation

I have a summation, with that goes for 1 to ∞. I suspect that it should converge to zero as `n -> ∞`.

```
 Sum[
  (a (a + 2)^2 + ab^2 - (a + 2) a^2 - 2 (a^2 + b^2))/((a^2 + b^2) ((a + 2)^2 + b^2)), 
  {a, 1, infinite}]
```

This summation has to become 0 when I change ∞ into a certain number, I want Mathematica to tell me that it indeed does lead to 0 in such a situation. It gives an answer so it converges, just now I want it to give me 0. Could somebody tell me how to tell Mathematica to do this?

Maybe by a nice plot? or just True/False for it being 0.

Thanks for your answers so far, I edited the message with it in mind, but I still dont have the definitive answer to my problem. Anybody knows?

Found this:

```
FullSimplify[Exists[{a, b}, Element[a, Integers] && Element[b, Integers] && ! MemberQ[Divisors[b], a] && a^2/b^2 == 2]]
```

Would something like that be of help?

Comment: Try `Sum[1/n^2,{n,1,Infinity}]` and `Sum[1/n^0.2,{n,1,Infinity}]`.

Comment: What do you mean? if it converges to 0, then the output for sum will be 0. If it is divergent it will be `Infinity` or `Interval[a,b]`

Comment: Did you try those two examples? One converges and spits out an answer, the other does not converge and tells you that it doesn't converge.

Comment: When I try: Sum[(a (a + 2)^2 + a b^2 - (a + 2) a^2 - 2 (a^2 + b^2))/((a^2 + b^2) ((a + 2)^2 + b^2)), {a, 1, Infinity}], I get an answer, that is a function of b. If I substitute in a simple b->1, it gives the answer 0.39082.... so it's not convergent to zero for all b.

Comment: You are out of luck. Your series does not converge to zero for any positive value of  `b`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving a logical contradiction involving integers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151517/resolving-a-logical-contradiction-involving-integers)

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[sum]

sum[b_] = Sum[(a (a + 2)^2 + a b^2 - (a + 2) a^2 - 
      2 (a^2 + b^2))/((a^2 + b^2) ((a + 2)^2 + b^2)), {a, 1, Infinity}] // 
  FullSimplify

(*  (16 + 96 b^2 + 105 b^4 + 33 b^6 + 2 b^8 - 
   b (1 + b^2) (4 + b^2) (4 + 3 b^2) π Coth[b π])/(4 (4 + b^2) (b + 
     b^3)^2)  *)
```

This function is even

```
sum[-b] == sum[b] // Simplify

(*  True  *)

Plot[sum[b], {b, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.75}]
```

[image]

The peak occurs at `b == 0`

```
Limit[sum[b], b -> 0]

(*  4 - π^2/3  *)

% // N

(*  0.710132  *)
```

The minimum is

```
NMinimize[sum[b], b]

(*  {0.183379, {b -> 2.99588}}  *)
```

As the magnitude of `b` increases the `Limit` is

```
Limit[sum[b], b -> Infinity]

(*  1/2  *)
```

Comment: @Mathematicabeginner - `sum` is not a function of `n` but rather of `d` and `y`. By inspection of the results of the summation it is clear that `sum` is zero for `d == 0`. Look at `Manipulate[
 Plot3D[sum[d, y], {d, -r, r}, {y, -r, r},
  PlotRange -> {-10, 10},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  PlotPoints -> 100],
 {{r, 1, "range"}, 0.01, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]`

Comment: @Mathematicabeginner - Look at the argument to `Plot3D`, define `sum` with `sum[d_, y_] = ...`

Comment: @Mathematicabeginner - works fine here. You may have some old definitions laying around, trying starting with a fresh kernel.

Comment: @Mathematicabeginner - I cannot access whatever you posted. I get the warning "Sorry, you do not have permission to access this item."